# Order By Split Column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column call it id:

```
4.1.2.10.0
4.1.2.3.0
4.1.2.4.0
6.1.20.0.0
6.1.3.0.0
...
etc...
```

What I'd like to do is include an ORDER BY statement that splits the
string, to become like this:

```
4.1.2.3.0
4.1.2.4.0
4.1.2.10.0
6.1.3.0.0
6.1.20.0.0
...
etc....
```

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `field1` with the actual field name:

```
select      *
from        tbl
order by    CInt(mid(field1,1,instr(1,field1,'.')-1)),
            CInt(mid(field1,instr(1,field1,'.')+1,instr(2,field1,'.')-1)),
            CInt(mid(field1,instr(3,field1,'.')+1,instr(4,field1,'.')-1)),
            CInt(mid(field1,instr(5,field1,'.')+1,instr(6,field1,'.')-1))
```

As noted by Gordon in the comments, this is prone to error. May want to await a better answer.

Comment: You can test w/ this file, link will be valid for 1 month: http://gofile.me/2iedJ/pQDYPiTQ (run query named "Query1", your table is named "tbl")

Comment: As a note, this will not work for something like "10.10.10.10".

Comment: . . Because the first argument to `instr()` is an offset.  Perhaps it's clearer if you consider "10000000.10000000.10000000.1000000".

Comment: When I wrote this I actually had nth occurrence in mind, as opposed to offset. I rarely use access. As is I think this will work as long as each number within the dots is no more than 2 digits?

Comment: The problem is that the offset error accumulates as you go deeper into the string.

Comment: I see what you mean re: the compounding effect, I'm not sure there is any way to do this without being able to identify the nth occurrence of the `.` though? I found this custom function but nothing built-in - http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=156440

Comment: It is possible.  You basically have the same problem in SQL Server if you use `charindex()` -- you end up with a bunch of complex nested string functions.  Unfortunately, MS Access doesn't have recursive subqueries or XML parsing to help fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the title suggests split:

```
Public Function SplitSort( _
    ByVal Value As String, _
    ByVal Element As Integer) _
    As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    SplitSort = Split(Value, ".")(Element - 1)

End Function
```

Now:

```
Order By 
    SplitSort([Fieldname], 1),
    SplitSort([Fieldname], 2),
    SplitSort([Fieldname], 3),
    SplitSort([Fieldname], 4),
    SplitSort([Fieldname], 5)
```