# Order By Split Column Content

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column call it id:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.2
1.19.1.1
1.2.3.1
1.2.3.2
1.19.1
1.19.1.2
```

...
etc...
What I'd like to do is include an ORDER BY statement that splits the string, to become like this:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.2
1.2.3.1
1.2.3.2
1.19.1
1.19.1.1
1.19.1.2
```

...
etc....
How would I do something like this?

I tried this solution [Order By Split Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934055/order-by-split-column) but doesn't work when length of number are doesn't same

Comment: Have you tried [Gustav's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28937678/3820271)? `Split` is the way to go here.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean, please? The function returns 0 (zero) for those parts not present to preserve the _Order By_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I tried this solution Order By Split Column but doesn't work **when length of number are doesn't same***

You can make them contain the same number of "." or tokens. For example, if you know that there can be a maximum of 4 dots (eg. 1.1.1.1.1) then you can run this script to concatenate the remaining ".0" tokens :

```
create table mytable(id varchar);

insert into mytable(id)
values  ('1'), ('1.1'), ('1.2'), ('1.2.1'), ('1.2.2'), ('1.19.1.1'), ('1.2.3.1'), ('1.2.3.2'), ('1.19.1'), ('1.19.1.2');

select id as original, id||
  case when length(id) - length(replace(id,'.','')) = 0 then ".0.0.0.0"
       when length(id) - length(replace(id,'.','')) = 1 then ".0.0.0"
       when length(id) - length(replace(id,'.','')) = 2 then ".0.0" 
       when length(id) - length(replace(id,'.','')) = 3 then ".0" 
  end as computed
from mytable;
```

You can run (each sql command at a time) the script [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) to test it

**Result :**

```
----------------------------
| original   |  computed   |
----------------------------
| 1          |  1.0.0.0.0  |
| 1.1        |  1.1.0.0.0  |
| 1.2        |  1.2.0.0.0  |
| 1.2.1      |  1.2.1.0.0  |
| 1.2.2      |  1.2.2.0.0  |
| 1.19.1.1   |  1.19.1.1.0 |
| 1.2.3.1    |  1.2.3.1.0  |
| 1.2.3.2    |  1.2.3.2.0  |
| 1.19.1     |  1.19.1.0.0 |
| 1.19.1.2   |  1.19.1.2.0 |
----------------------------
```

After this conversion you can apply the script that you mentioned.

Comment: Sadly, replace doesn't work in MS-access accessed by VB.NET, does anybody give explanation use INSTR like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834536/exception-when-trying-to-execute-replace-against-ms-access ..?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need solution for MS Access SQL, not MS SQL. If so, then [Gustav's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937678/5339178) from topic you mentioned works fine without any change